# Refund value estimation for one leg of the return journey

Tags: air-travel, airlines, refunds, spicejet

I had booked an DXB-AMD return journey on Spicejet through Makemytrip.com. The total cost for the booking was INR 18,132. The booking confirmation showed that out of this, INR 300 was "convenience fee". On the day of the DXB-AMD flight, Spicejet cancelled the flight without providing any rebooking options, so I had to book another flight to get to AMD. When I filed the refund claim with makemytrip for cancelled flight, they told me that refund amount will be INR 9346 "approximately" but now they are saying that the refund amount is INR 8063. When I asked them why this change in amount, they said that original amount was an approximation and the new amount is the actual amount paid by the airline. How can I verify that Makemytrip is not screwing me? The full conversation with Makemytrip is here if anyone is interested: https://www.facebook.com/makemytrip/posts/10153000248246031?comment_id=10153000598961031&notif_t=feed_comment

Comment: to make sure we get it right, what was your initial itinerary? was it *only* a one way (DXB-AMD). Also, the refund amount you're asking is for DXB-AMD so how did you get to AMD (same travel agent, same airline)?

Comment: My initial itinerary was return trip from DXB to AMD, so DXB-AMD-DXB. Since Spicejet cancelled DXB-AMD flight, I had to book Jet Airways at the very last minute through a different travel agent.

Comment: Have you tried calling SpiceJet and asking them how much they have actually refunded? That will clearly give you the delta between what they refunded and what you received, and so will make it clear who is at fault

Comment: Also, you will *probably* have to escalate this matter multiple times with MakeMyTrip since it is an impossibly difficult task to make the tier 1 agents understand stuff beyond the basic operations. They might not comprehend the difference between a cancellation initiated by you and one initiated by the airline. Expect to spend a few months on resolving this if not resolved with the 1st escalation

Comment: Check at http://changes.spicejet.com/GetBooking.aspx As per spicejet there will be no charge for refund in case of cancellation. Either the 2 flight legs had differing fares (very common) and the MMT estimator was just dividing the price by 2, or MMT is skimming off the top of your refund..

Comment: The link you provided doesn't show my booking. I have had this problem with Spicejet website for sometime now. But thanks for your comments. I think I will just believe MMT on this one.

Answer (score 2):

Not much you can do besides:

1. Asking for evidence from MakeMyTrip on how they calculate the refund, and their logic and reasoning for it.
2. Ask SpiceJet for a letter stating what the refund should be, if they have a policy on this and are willing to do it.
3. If you can prove they're skimming off the top, you can then take them to a disputes tribunal / court, given the original letter, and they'll likely have to justify the change.
4. Consider tweeting them about it. Often the public attention gets you more help.